# Why the falling rectangle become more and more as the time goes by?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to the pygame.
I wrote a simple game of avoid the falling rectangle. But I found that as the time goes by, the falling rectangle become more and more, and some of the rectangle can't let `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany` produce when they meet the player.Is there any bug in my code?

This is my code.

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 25
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()

#define the player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
          super(Player, self).__init__()
          self.surf = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
          self.surf.fill((123, 123, 123))
          self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
          self.rect.y = 550
          self.rect.x = 175

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        """
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
        """
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

        #keep player on the screen
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        elif self.rect.right > 400:
            self.rect.right = 400

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center = (random.randint(0, 400), 0))
        self.speed = random.randint(5, 10)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed)
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        #initialization
        pygame.init()

        #create the screen object
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 600))

        #instantiate the player
        self.player = Player()
        self.score = 0

        #create enemies
        self.ADDENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.ADDENEMY, 250)

        self.enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)

    def run(self):
        running = True

        #main loop
        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        running = False
                elif event.type == QUIT:
                    running = False
                elif (event.type == self.ADDENEMY):
                    new_enemy = Enemy()
                    self.enemies.add(new_enemy)
                    self.score = self.score + 1
                    self.all_sprites.add(new_enemy)

            pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            self.player.update(pressed_keys)
            self.enemies.update()
            self.screen.fill((0,0,0))
            #draw the player to the screen
            for entity in self.all_sprites:
                self.screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.player, self.enemies):
                print 'score: ' + str(self.score)
                self.score = 0

            screen_image = pygame.surfarray.array3d(pygame.display.get_surface())        
            #update the display
            pygame.display.update()
            #fpsclock.tick(FPS)
        #return reward, screen_image

game = Game()
game.run()
```

After running the code about five minutes, the bug appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to kill the enemy sprites when they cross the bottom of the screen not the top (y=0 is the top of the screen, y=600 the bottom):

```
if self.rect.top > 600:  # Set it to 550 to see how they disappear.
    self.kill()
```

Edit: To kill the collided sprite use the value that `spritecollideany` returns which can be either `None` or the collided sprite:

```
collided_sprite = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.player, self.enemies)
if collided_sprite is not None:
    print('score:', self.score)
    self.score = 0
    collided_sprite.kill()
```

Note that this deletes only one sprite per frame. If you want to delete several sprites at the same time, better use [`spritecollide`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) and pass `True` as the `dokill` argument.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. Excuse me, how can I kill the rectangle which hit the player?

Comment: I've edited the answer, even though that belongs in another question and you can probably find lots of other posts regarding this topic.

Comment: It actually looks like that this hasn't been asked before. Maybe I should ask and answer this myself.